# Using ViewBag in as route value in Html.BeginForm converts ViewBag value to lower case

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encryption, html.beginform

I am trying to pass an encrypted string through BeginForm's route collection by delivering it in a ViewBag like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Go", "Process", new { id = ViewBag.Id }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "seperate-sections fill-up form-horizontal", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

`ViewBag.Id` is a dynamically encrypted string such as: `g9IPGGXm4jw=`

Unfortunately when it reaches to my controller via form submit; it comes in lower case like : `g9ipggxm4jw=`  which causes an exception on decryption process.

Do someone have an idea about where it becomes lower case?

Comment: I think it's encoding problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. The problem was routing!

My routing has force lowercase definition as `routes.LowercaseUrls = true;`

So it was automatically converting the url to lowercase and my encryption was getting broken!